# MS SQL Server function performance issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hopefully somebody can help me with a MS SQL function performance issue.
I have the following function which matches users in the same table. User A is searching for users he can match with. If he finds a User B that matches his criteria, User B checks wether User A matches their criteria. If they have already matched they are in the ExcludedCandidates table.
The problem I have is that the query takes too long.

I tried a lot of things but have no more ideas on how to improve it.

Maybe some indices or changes to the query could help here.
Any help would be appreaciated.

```
create function [dbo].[FindUser](@UserId uniqueidentifier, @dis int, @gen int, @age datetime, @f int, @ti int, @s int, @La float, @Lo float)
returns @T table (UserId uniqueidentifier, Profile nvarchar(MAX), Filter nvarchar(MAX), F int, I bit, IsP bit)
as
BEGIN
    
    declare @Tmp table(UserId uniqueidentifier, a nvarchar(MAX), b nvarchar(MAX), c int, d bit, e bit)

    DECLARE @source geography
    select @source = geography::Point(@La, @Lo, 4326)

    insert into @Tmp
    SELECT TOP 10 U.UserId, U.Profile, U.F, @s as Fil, U.Ve, U.TT from Users AS U WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE ((@gen & U.Ge) != 0) AND
    (Sea = 1 OR Sea = 2) AND
    @s = U.Sear AND
    U.La is not null and U.Lon is not null AND
    @dis >= (@source.STDistance(geography::Point(U.La, U.Lon, 4326)) / 1000) AND
    (@f <= YEAR(GETUTCDATE()) - YEAR(@age)) AND (@ti >= YEAR(GETUTCDATE()) - YEAR(@age)) AND
    U.UserId != @UserId
    and not exists
    (select TOP 1 IC1.InitiatorUserId from ExcludedCandidates AS IC1 with (NOLOCK)
    where (IC1.InitiatorUserId = @UserId and IC1.PartnerUserId = U.UserId) OR
    (IC1.InitiatorUserId = U.UserId and IC1.PartnerUserId = @UserId)) 
    and exists(

        SELECT U.UserId from Users UserP with (NOLOCK)
        WHERE ((JSON_VALUE(UserP.Filter, '$.gender') & U.Ge) != 0) AND
        (Sea = 1 OR Sea = 2) AND
        @s = Sea AND
        (JSON_VALUE(UserP.Filter, '$.age.lo') <= YEAR(GETUTCDATE()) - YEAR(@age)) AND (JSON_VALUE(UserP.Filter, '$.age.up') >= YEAR(GETUTCDATE()) - YEAR(@age)) AND
         JSON_VALUE(UserP.Filter, '$.di') >= (geography::Point(UserP.La, UserP.Lon, 4326).STDistance(geography::Point(@La, @Lo, 4326)) / 1000) AND
        UserId = U.UserId

    )
    order by U.Sea DESC
    
    insert into @T
    select UserId, a, b, c, d, e from @Tmp


    return 
END
```

Indexes we use

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NonClusteredIndex_Users_Search] ON [dbo].[Users]
(
    [Sea] DESC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NonClusteredIndex_Users_SearchSearchState] ON [dbo].[Users]
(
    [Sear] ASC,
    [Sea] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [Filter],
    [La],
    [Lon]) WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: What you have here is a multi-line table value function, which are known to perform poorly. You will very likely find that converting it to an inline-table value function will provide much better performance.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks How can I do that?

Comment: #1) .. How is it being called? #2) Do you have a table schema with Indexes available to review?

It's hard to suggest index changes if we don't know what you already have. Also, if you are calling this function inside another query using an APPLY, that could be causing more problems in itself.

Comment: @Jason Thanks!  #1) It's called from C# using ADO.NET #2) Added Indexes

Comment: Once more question ... if this is being called directly from C# code, why not use a stored procedure instead?

Comment: @Jason Do you think it is faster? How can I return an table? I only use it sometimes to retunr single values as output definition.

Comment: @Maza Are you pulling this just one at a time for each user? And you're only pulling one user at a time, not a set of them?

Why so many parameters?

What does your execution plan tell you when you run it in SSMS?

Comment: @Paul Currently only once and we need this parameters to seach for user.

Comment: I think a stored procedure would be much better here then for a consistent execution plan. What version of SQL Server are you using? Without seeing your execution plan, it's impossible to know the right answer here, but something you might want to try is creating an index on everything in the where clause (ordered sanely), and included everything else, for both the main and subqueries.

Answer (score 2):

What you have here is a multi-line table value function, which are known to perform poorly. You will very likely find that converting it to an inline-table value function will provide much better performance.

Due to not having the definition of the other objects, I can't test this (so any syntax errors have not been checked), however, this is a literal conversion to a inline table-value function. There is, however, likely more you can do here (for example `@dis >= (V.srv.STDistance(geography::Point(U.La, U.Lon, 4326)) / 1000)` is not SARGable), but without a true goal, along with sample data and expected results, this would be impossible to do more than guess at:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FindUser](@UserId uniqueidentifier, @dis int, @gen int, @age datetime, @f int, @ti int, @s int, @La float, @Lo float)
RETURNS table --@T table (UserId uniqueidentifier, Profile nvarchar(MAX), Filter nvarchar(MAX), F int, I bit, IsP bit)
AS RETURN

    
    --declare @Tmp table(UserId uniqueidentifier, a nvarchar(MAX), b nvarchar(MAX), c int, d bit, e bit)
    --
    --DECLARE @source geography
    --select @source = geography::Point(@La, @Lo, 4326)

    SELECT TOP (10)
           U.UserId,
           U.Profile,
           U.F,
           @s as Fil,
           U.Ve,
           U.TT
    FROM dbo.Users AS U-- WITH (NOLOCK) --Unless you really undersatnd what NOLOCK does, you shou.dn't be using this.
         CROSS APPLY(VALUES(geography::Point(@La, @Lo, 4326)))V(src)
    WHERE ((@gen & U.Ge) != 0)
      AND (Sea = 1 OR Sea = 2)
      AND @s = U.Sear
      AND U.La IS NOT NULL
      and U.Lon IS NOT NULL
      AND @dis >= (V.srv.STDistance(geography::Point(U.La, U.Lon, 4326)) / 1000)
      AND (@f <= YEAR(GETUTCDATE()) - YEAR(@age)) AND (@ti >= YEAR(GETUTCDATE()) - YEAR(@age))
      AND U.UserId != @UserId
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 --No need for a TOP (1) here
                      FROM ExcludedCandidates AS IC1-- with (NOLOCK) --Unless you really undersatnd what NOLOCK does, you shou.dn't be using this.
                      WHERE (IC1.InitiatorUserId = @UserId AND IC1.PartnerUserId = U.UserId)
                         OR (IC1.InitiatorUserId = U.UserId AND IC1.PartnerUserId = @UserId)) 
      AND exists(SELECT 1
               from Users UserP-- with (NOLOCK) --Unless you really undersatnd what NOLOCK does, you shou.dn't be using this.
               WHERE ((JSON_VALUE(UserP.Filter, '$.gender') & U.Ge) != 0)
                 AND (Sea = 1 OR Sea = 2)
                 AND @s = Sea
                 AND (JSON_VALUE(UserP.Filter, '$.age.lo') <= YEAR(GETUTCDATE()) - YEAR(@age))
                 AND (JSON_VALUE(UserP.Filter, '$.age.up') >= YEAR(GETUTCDATE()) - YEAR(@age))
                 AND JSON_VALUE(UserP.Filter, '$.di') >= (geography::Point(UserP.La, UserP.Lon, 4326).STDistance(geography::Point(@La, @Lo, 4326)) / 1000)
                 AND UserId = U.UserId)
    ORDER BY U.Sea DESC;

GO
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. I changed it but the same outcome, still very slow. We have round 15k users in the table where User A matches to all users but only one User matches to User A back. Maybe this info helps also. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think I would change this to a stored procedure if you don't have an explicit reason you need a function. You create a function to include the results in a select statement with another table. It doesn't sound like that's what you are doing here ...

Also, I would separate the logic that parses the JSON data from the table and perform that apart from the main query. Those parsing statements are probably taking you the most time. You can potentially optimize that separately.

Last, ensure you have an index on your `ExcludedCandidates` tables like the following ...

```
CREATE INDEX [IX_ExcludedCandidates_UserIDs] ON [dbo].[ExcludedCandidates] (
    InitiatorUserId, PartnerUserId
)
```

Here's the PROC definition I would try ...

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[FindUser] (
    @UserId uniqueidentifier,
    @dis int,
    @gen int,
    @age datetime,
    @f int,
    @ti int,
    @s int,
    @La float,
    @Lo float
) AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @source geography = geography::Point(@La, @Lo, 4326)

    SELECT
        *
    INTO
        #UserInfo
    FROM (
        SELECT
            UserId,
            La,
            Lon,
            Sea,
            JSON_VALUE(Filter, '$.gender') gender,
            JSON_VALUE(Filter, '$.age.lo') age_lo,
            JSON_VALUE(Filter, '$.age.up') age_up,
            JSON_VALUE(Filter, '$.di') di
        FROM
            Users
        ) S
    WHERE
        di >= (geography::Point(La, Lon, 4326).STDistance(geography::Point(@La, @Lo, 4326)) / 1000) 

    SELECT TOP 10
        U.UserId,
        U.Profile,
        U.F,
        @s AS Fil,
        U.Ve,
        U.TT
    FROM
        Users AS U WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE
        ((@gen & U.Ge) != 0) AND (
            Sea = 1
            OR Sea = 2
        ) AND 
        @s = U.Sear AND
        U.La IS NOT NULL AND
        U.Lon IS NOT NULL AND
        @dis >= (@source.STDistance(geography::Point(U.La, U.Lon, 4326)) / 1000) AND 
        (@f <= YEAR(GETUTCDATE()) - YEAR(@age)) AND 
        (@ti >= YEAR(GETUTCDATE()) - YEAR(@age)) AND 
        U.UserId != @UserId AND 
        NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT TOP 1
                IC1.InitiatorUserId
            FROM
                ExcludedCandidates AS IC1 WITH (NOLOCK)
            WHERE (
                    IC1.InitiatorUserId = @UserId AND
                    IC1.PartnerUserId = U.UserId
                ) OR (
                    IC1.InitiatorUserId = U.UserId AND
                    IC1.PartnerUserId = @UserId
                )
        ) AND 
        EXISTS(
            SELECT
                U.UserId
            FROM
                #UserInfo UserP WITH (NOLOCK)
            WHERE
                (UserP.gender & U.Ge) != 0 AND 
                UserP.Sea IN (1, 2) AND
                @s = UserP.Sea AND (UserP.age_lo <= YEAR(GETUTCDATE()) - YEAR(@age)) AND 
                (UserP.age_up >= YEAR(GETUTCDATE()) - YEAR(@age)) AND 
                UserP.UserId = U.UserId
        )
    ORDER BY
        U.Sea DESC
END
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried it but it takes longer. I guess that all 150k user will be loaded inside #UserInfo takes also a long time.